# Parse docker-compose.yml with yq to generate documentation

Tags: docker-compose, yq

I'm trying to parse my docker-compose file using `yq` (the go implementation from https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) to auto-generate a documentation using asciidoc.

My docker-compose.yml looks fairly simple and does nothing out of the ordinary:

```yaml
---
version: "3.3"
services:

  # prometheus metrics
  node_exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:latest
    container_name: node_exporter
    labels:
      description: Prometheus exporter to monitor system metrics
    restart: always
    command:
      - --path.rootfs=/host
    pid: host
    network_mode: host
    # ports:
    #   - 9100:9100
    # The network_mode: host tells docker to run the container as if it was running on the
    # server itself, so all ports exports by the container will directly be mapped to the server.
    volumes:
      - /:/host:ro,rslave
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro

  # prometheus metrics
  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:latest
    container_name: cadvisor
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 9110
    ports:
      - 9110:8080
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro

  # Mange containers
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:alpine
    container_name: portainer
    command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --admin-password-file /tmp/portainer_passwords
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9990:9000
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - portainer_data:/data
      - ./assets/portainer.passwd:/tmp/portainer_passwords
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro

volumes:
  portainer_data:
```

I want some information for each service. Most important to me is the image. container name restart and ports. Plus maybe labels -> description which is a field I use for some documentation (what does the respective service actually do).

I don't know how I can get these fields for the respective service combined. When I run `yq eval '.services.[] | .container_name, .services.[] | .image' $composeFile` I first get 3 lines with the container name and then 3 lines with the image.

```
node_exporter
cadvisor
portainer
prom/node-exporter:latest
gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:latest
portainer/portainer-ce:alpine
```

This result is not grouped by service. I'd prefer something like this:

```
node_exporter
prom/node-exporter:latest
cadvisor
gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:latest
portainer
portainer/portainer-ce:alpine
```

Or since I want to generate asciidoc,the perfect solution would be this:

```
|node_exporter |prom/node-exporter:latest
|cadvisor |gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:latest
|portainer |portainer/portainer-ce:alpine
```

This way I can generate the body of an asciidoc table with information on my services for my documentation.

Anyone got an idea how I can get `yq` to work as I indend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `.services.[]` starts a new iteration. Do it once and extract all you need from there:

```bash
yq eval '.services.[] | "|" + .container_name + "| " + .image'
```

```
|node_exporter| prom/node-exporter:latest
|cadvisor| gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:latest
|portainer| portainer/portainer-ce:alpine
```

Comment: When I use your suggestion I get `Error: Scalars not yet supported for addition`.

Comment: I'm using yq 4.2.0.

Comment: @SebastianSommerfeld Your version 4.2.0 is [quite old](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases) and lacks a lot of core implementations. You could update your version to at least 4.4.0 which supports more string operations, or better yet to the latest version   (currently 4.26.1), or use another YAML processor (e.g. [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)), or use external tools for post-processing, e.g. GNU paste: `paste <(yq eval '.services.[].container_name' file.yaml) <(yq eval '.services.[].image' file.yaml)`.

Comment: Updating to 4.26.1 did the trick. Works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot for your help.